# Notes : Addr821 in NotesName class

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

Addr821 in NotesName class returns empty string if the notes mail address does not contain @Domain at the end of the address. However it does not work if @Domain exists. How can I judge the Mail address if it is a Notes mail or an E-mail address?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the [Addr821](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ADDR821_PROPERTY_6733.html) method in the [NotesName](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESNAME_CLASS.html) class is to take any email address that looks like this:

```
"Richard's Fake Address" <rhs@richardsdomain.com>
```

And return this:

```
rhs@richardsdomain.com
```

It is not designed to distinguish between valid Notes addresses and valid RFC821 addresses. It's technically possible, in fact, for the same string to be both a valid Notes address and a valid RFC821 address.

Comment: I tried once (some 20 years back, R3.21 or so) to create a domain called e.g. site.nl, with a dot. In the end, I had to reinstall the whole server using a domain name without the dot.

Comment: The RFCs actually allow local addresses without an @domain, so technically "richard" can be both a valid Notes address and a valid RFC821 address. An address like that could even be non-local if you set you the search suffix on your resolver to provide the domain, though it probably doesn't get delivered by modern SMTP software with reasonable anti-spam settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the NotesName.isHierarchical property ? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ISHIERARCHICAL_PROPERTY.html

Comment: Thank for reply. "isHierarchical" is "False indicates that the name is an Internet address or a flat name". In this case, how can distinguish it? I currently just check if there is "." char after "@". If there is the char, it is internet address. I don't think this is good solution but I have no idea. Do you have ant suggestion?